# Select Next mysql row without refer to id

Tags: php, mysql, select, row

This is My Table:

```
    #id#    #cpc#
    100      10
     87       9
     101      9
     4        6
     188      5
```

it's sorted DESC according to 'cpc' column.
I Want to extract the rows one by one **without referring to id**.. such as you can see it.

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY cpc DESC
first result is with the id 100
next one is with id 101 and cpc 9 not 87.. as the id is only increasing.. so it selects wrong rows not as what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in php:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY cpc DESC");

while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id = $row['id'];
$cpc = $row['cpc'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Select them using `limit` and `offset`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY cpc DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

Then:

```
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your ordering.

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM table 
ORDER BY cpc DESC,
         Id ASC
```